# Python change file extension when user changes save as type in asksaveasfilename

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am working on making a simple journal program with python tkinter that allows the user to write text inside of a `Text` widget and save it to a file using the file as a "journal".  Using the `asksaveasfilename` I can save a file but it will not save it with a file extension.  I realize you can use `.defaultextension` but I would like the user to save the file with the extension that they choose.  Here is my code:

```
from datetime import datetime
now = datetime.now()
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import font

journal_name = ""

def save_journal():
    journal_name = filedialog.asksaveasfilename(filetypes = [("Text file", ".txt"), ("Python file", ".py"), ("All Types", ".*")])
    file = open(journal_name, "a")
    file.write("%s/%s/%s" % (now.month, now.day, now.year))
    file.write("  ")
    file.write(text_box.get("1.0", "end-1c"))
    file.write("\n\n")
    file.close()


#make a gui window

app = Tk()
app.title("Journal Program")
app.iconbitmap(app, "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Notepad++\\Files\\journalicon.ico")
app.resizable(0,0)


text_font = font.Font(family="Segoe UI", size=11)

#main frame
main_frame = ttk.Frame(app, padding = "5 5 5 5")
main_frame.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="nsew")


text_box = Text(main_frame, wrap = WORD, height = 15, width = 70, font = text_font)

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(main_frame)
scrollbar.config(command = text_box.yview)

text_box.config(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set)
text_box.grid(column = 1, columnspan = 3, row = 2, sticky = "es")

scrollbar.grid(column = 4, row = 2, sticky = "ns")

save_button = ttk.Button(main_frame, text = "Save", command = save_journal)
save_button.grid(column = 3, row = 3, sticky = S + E, pady = '5')


app.mainloop()
```

What I want is for the user to be able to choose a file type (python for example) from the save as window, and for that to be the file extension on the file that is saved. I am not sure if it is even possible but if it is I would really appreciate the help, I have not been able to find any information on this sort of thing.

I hope this isn't too much code for a stack overflow question.  I tried to slim it down to a minimal program.  Also I realize that the code could be optimized, but I am still learning python and am trying to figure things out.  Any comments or help on how to optimize this code would also be much appreciated.  Thank you all in advance.

Comment: just save the file with the desired extension.

Comment: Well I would like to make it so the user can type a file name without having to put in the extension.

Comment: Your current code works fine for me already - if I type in `test.txt` in the filename dialog, a file `test.txt` gets written.

Comment: I realize that, what I am asking is if there is a way to type in `test` in the filename dialog and choose one of the file types and have the file extension of the chosen file type added as the file extension. Does that make sense?

Comment: Are you asking how to do `journalname = journalname + ".txt"`?

Comment: @Brian Oakley No, what I am asking is when the user saves a file and chooses a file type, I want to add the file extension of that file type as the extension of the file. For example, if a user types a name of "New file" into the `asksaveasfilename` dialog box and chooses "Python file", then the program saves the file as "New file.py". Hopefully that answers your question.